# Вертикальное и горизонтальное выравнивание текста по центру (Grid CSS)

Tags: html, css

> "ПЕС И ЛИСА ИГРАЛИСЬ ВО ДВОРЕ ДО УТРА   НОЧИ ЕЛИ КОНЕЙ"

⠀⠀⠀⠀**И**

> "ТЕРЕМОК И БЕЛЫЙ КОСТЕР ЕЛИ КОШКУ ЗАТЕМ ЕЛИ ЧЕЛОВЕКА У КАМИНА"

Данные два текста нормально выглядят в блоках(они выровнялись по центру), но остальной текст в блоках не выравнивается по центру.

**Как в остальных блоках выровнять текст по центру вертикально и горизонтально.**

```css
.Сategory_Main_Block {
  padding-top: 2vw;
  padding-bottom: 2vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 15.5%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, max-content);
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 2vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.Сategory_Block_1 {
  background: #20B2AA;
  border-radius: 1.5vw;
  margin: 0;
}

.Сategory_img_1 {
  background: gray;
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5vw;
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5vw;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vw;
}

.Сategory_name_1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<section class="Сategory_Main_Block">


  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ПЕС И ЛИСА ИГРАЛИСЬ ВО ДВОРЕ ДО УТРА НОЧИ ЕЛИ КОНЕЙ</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ХАДО 90</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ЭКОНОМИКА</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">КОСТЕР И СВЕТ</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ДЯДЯ ФЕДОР</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ШАНХАЙ</figcaption>
  </figure>


  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">БРАТВА</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ОФИЦИАЛЬНО</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ТЕРЕМОК И БЕЛЫЙ КОСТЕР ЕЛИ КОШКУ ЗАТЕМ ЕЛИ ЧЕЛОВЕКА У КАМИНА</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">МОЛНИЯ</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">КОРЕШКИ</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ЮГ МАГНИТА</figcaption>
  </figure>


</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они не по центру, просто заполнили весь блок. Можно через flex:

```css
.Сategory_Main_Block{
padding-top:2vw;
padding-bottom:2vw; 
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 15.5%);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, max-content);
column-gap:1vw;
row-gap:2vw;
margin-left:2vw;
}

.Сategory_Block_1{
background:#20B2AA;
border-radius: 1.5vw;
margin:0;
display: flex; /*+*/
flex-direction: column; /*+*/
}

.Сategory_img_1{
background:gray;
border-top-right-radius: 1.5vw;
border-top-left-radius: 1.5vw;  
width:100%; 
height:12vw;                   
}

.Сategory_name_1{
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
font-size:18px; 
color:black;
font-family:arial;
flex: 1; /*+*/
display: flex; /*+*/
align-items: center; /*+*/
word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<section class="Сategory_Main_Block"> 


<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ПЕС И ЛИСА ИГРАЛИСЬ ВО ДВОРЕ ДО УТРА 
 НОЧИ ЕЛИ КОНЕЙ</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ХАДО 90</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ЭКОНОМИКА</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">КОСТЕР И СВЕТ</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ДЯДЯ ФЕДОР</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ШАНХАЙ</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">БРАТВА</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ОФИЦИАЛЬНО</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ТЕРЕМОК И БЕЛЫЙ КОСТЕР ЕЛИ КОШКУ ЗАТЕМ ЕЛИ ЧЕЛОВЕКА У КАМИНА</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">МОЛНИЯ</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">КОРЕШКИ</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">ЮГ МАГНИТА</figcaption>
</figure>


</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ли тоже самое проделать с применением grid без flex ?